# Loop through data stored in buffer in C

Tags: c, audio, wav, file-pointer

I have a .dat file with two columns, time & channel of audio data. I am trying to just read the column channel, write it in a different .dat file and save it.

In the code, I have stored the file in a buffer and I'm able to read the values in the column. Now I'm trying to put the second column in another file named out.dat, but it looks like it's not writing anything into the file. Here's what I've done.

```
int main(){

double a=0;
double b=0;
int bufferLength = 330750;
char buffer[bufferLength];

FILE *fp = fopen("original.dat", "r");
if (!fp){
    printf("Cant open file\n");
    return -1;
}

FILE *outfp= fopen("out.dat", "w");
if(outfp == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to create file\n");
}


while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {  
    if (2==sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a,&b)){  // Just printing col 2 //
        printf("b: %f\n", b);
    }
}
for(bufferLength=0; bufferLength<330750; bufferLength++){
    fputs(&bufferLength, outfp);
}

printf("File transferred\n");
fclose(outfp);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `printf("b: %f\n", b);` Write to the output file here. `fprintf(outfp, "%f\n", b);`

Comment: I believe I can now see the data in the out.dat file. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp
Hi Johny, I am now trying to put the values stored in the file pointer into an array. 
For example, I tried printf("%f", outfp); to print the float values in out.dat and put it into an array. But the output is wrong.
Do you have any idea on how I can put values from the file pointer into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can copy the data into the new file and count the numbers with:

```
int counter = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {  
    if (2 == sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a, &b)) {
        counter += 1;
        fprintf(outfp, "%f\n", b);
    }
}
```

Then create an array and read the file again:

```
double *data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * counter);
if (!data) { /* handle error */ }
rewind(fp);  // If rewind is not available use fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)
int index = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {  
    if (2 == sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a, &b)) {
        data[index++] = b;  // Just saving b??
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can combine these 2 loops and use `realloc` to allocate memory for the array as you go:

```
double *data = NULL;  // Important: needs to be initialized to NULL
int counter = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp)) {  
    if (2 == sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf", &a, &b)) {
        double *temp = realloc(data, sizeof(*data) * (counter + 1));
        if (!temp) { /* handle error.... */ }
        data = temp;
        data[counter++] = b;
        fprintf(outfp, "%f\n", b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Johny,
I tried the first two codes to count the numbers and create an array. They both worked. Thank you !